# Remove "INFO" while logging the text using log4net

Tags: log4net

When i log some text to the log file using log4net.log.info() method, it looks like below.

INFO - 10/17/2011 9:50:32 AM some text goes here

Here i don't need the "INFO" text to be added on to the log file. how do i prevent this? please help me

Answer (score 1):

I assume your configuration will contain a line like this:

```
<conversionPattern value="%-5level - %date %message%newline" />
```

This instructs log4net to print the loglevel (in your case INFO). Simply remove the level like this:

```
<conversionPattern value="%date %message%newline" />
```

More information on this can be found [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html).